# Run both Classic and YAML pipelines in parallel

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-yaml

Is it possible to run both classic and YAML pipeline in parallel?
More context: we are migrating from classic to YAML and want to make sure the switch is smooth. We'd like to run them both for a few runs and make sure YAML pipeline is good before disabling classic pipeline. We have some conditional stages based on develop, master and release branches
Thanks!

Comment: Did you manage to solve the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should be able to do so. Just make sure to use the same [triggers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/triggers?view=azure-devops#classic-build-pipelines-and-yaml-pipelines) for both pipeline types. Keep in mind that each pipeline consumes the agent pool (so if you have 1+ concurrent runs then it should be fine). Also review the actual tasks of your pipelines and think about any potential risk of running them in parallel (may be there is a target resource lock for change or any other circumstances that will prevent or fail your definition from run even with the same set of tasks and parameters).